# Recursively touch files with file

Tags: bash, shell, file, touch

I have a directory that contains sub-directories and other files and would like to update the date/timestamps recursively with the date/timestamp of another file/directory.

I'm aware that:

```
touch -r file directory
```

changes the date/timestamp for the file or directory with the others, but nothing within it. There's also the find version which is:

```
find . -exec touch -mt 201309300223.25 {} +\;
```

which would work fine if i could specify the actual file/directory and use anothers date/timestamp. Is there a simple way to do this? even better, is there a way to avoid changing/updating timestamps when doing a 'cp'?

Comment: So you want all files/dirs to have the same or another file/dir, or each one having the same as the "symmetric" one?

Comment: @fedorqui - either way would be fine. symmetric would be awesome though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even better, is there a way to avoid changing/updating timestamps when doing a 'cp'?

Yes, use `cp` with the `-p` option:

> **-p**
>
> same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
>
> **--preserve**
>
> preserve the specified attributes (default:
>   mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes:
>   context, links, xattr, all

#### Example

```
$ ls -ltr
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me  368 Apr 24 10:50 old_file
$ cp old_file not_maintains    <----- does not preserve time
$ cp -p old_file do_maintains  <----- does preserve time
$ ls -ltr
total 28
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me  368 Apr 24 10:50 old_file
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me  368 Apr 24 10:50 do_maintains   <----- does preserve time
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me  368 Sep 30 11:33 not_maintains  <----- does not preserve time
```

---

To recursively `touch` files on a directory based on the symmetric file on another path, you can try something like the following:

```
find /your/path/ -exec touch -r $(echo {} | sed "s#/your/path#/your/original/path#g") {} \;
```

It is not working for me, but I guess it is a matter of try/test a little bit more.

Comment: -preserve works perfectly. If there's a way to do what my main question addresses and it's a simple solution i'd love to know. i'll mark this as the correct answer when it allows me. thank you :)

Comment: I am doing some tests in my machine, I guess I will update my answer within few minutes : )

Comment: no worries, you've addressed the main thing i was looking to do. a solution for the touch command would be very nice though since i do find myself having to `touch -r file file` quite often and go about it manually. :/

Comment: @CocoaPuffs good to read it worked to you :) I just updated my answer with a `find` command to recursively touch files. It is not working to me, I guess I am close and have to trick a little bit more... will update if I get it.

Comment: it's not an easy one, although it seems like it should be. thanks for taking the time to provide the other attempt/example though.

Answer (score 0):

As fedorqui said, `cp -p` is preferred but maybe you forgot the -p and need to replace timestamps with their originals recursively without recopying all the files. I tried nesting a shell command with $() but the modified string is not returned by sed properly. Here is a modification that works:

```
find /Destination -exec bash -c 'touch -r "${0/Destination/Source}" "$0"' {} \;
```

This assumes a duplicate file/ folder tree of Source: `/Source` and Destination: `/Destination`

1. `find` searches the Destination for all files & dirs (which need timestamps) and `-exec ... {}` runs a command for each result.
2. `bash -c ' ... '` executes a shell command using bash.
3. `$0` holds the find result.
4. `touch -r {timestamped_file} {file_to_stamp}` uses a bash replace command `${string/search/replace}` to set timestamp source appropriately.
5. the Source and Destination directories are quoted to handle dirs with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to 'cp -p', you can (re)create an old timestamp using 'touch -t'. See the man page of 'touch' for more details.

```
touch -t 200510071138 old_file.dat
```

Comment: i want to recursively update a file(s)/directory(s) timestamp(s) with anothers. i don't see how this helps.